# unable to install haproxy 1.5 on centos 6.5

Tags: haproxy, centos6.5

I am trying to install haproxy on my centos 6.5 server. I am using the command

```
 yum install haproxy
```

This command installs a version 1.4.x. I have also looked at the following links, but could not get it to work

http://virtuallyhyper.com/2013/05/configure-haproxy-to-load-balance-sites-with-ssl/

http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/09/10/how-to-get-ssl-with-haproxy-getting-rid-of-stunnel-stud-nginx-or-pound/

https://github.com/bluerail/haproxy-centos

how do i install it?

Answer (score 1):

You can build the RPM as follows:

```
mkdir -p rpmbuild/{BUILD,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}
sudo yum -y install pcre-devel openssl-devel
cd rpmbuild/SOURCES
curl -L -O http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/src/haproxy-1.5.3.tar.gz
tar zxf haproxy-1.5.3.tar.gz
cd ..

cp -p SOURCES/haproxy-1.5.3/examples/haproxy.spec SPECS/haproxy153.spec
sed -i 's/Release: .*/Release:  %{?_release:%{_release}}%{!?_release:1}/' SPECS/haproxy153.spec
sed -i 's/USE_PCRE=1 /USE_PCRE=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_ZLIB=1 /' SPECS/haproxy153.spec
rpmbuild --define "_topdir `pwd`" --define "_release 2" -bb SPECS/haproxy153.spec
```

(I use a local directory and set the release number otherwise it is the same as http://qiita.com/uemura/items/e822c1ed505b9fe0208f)

Install

```
scp RPMS/x86_64/haproxy-1.5.3-2.x86_64.rpm root@somewhere:~/
somewhere# yum localinstall ~/haproxy-1.5.3-2.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

You could install from source using one of these tar bundles:

http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/src/

You will probably need to install the following bundles to compile from source:

```
yum openssl-devel pcre-devel make gcc
```

Here's also a [script](https://gist.github.com/ChrisMcKee/9cdb1bf9c5314f320ec5) which I presume would work on your environment